# Improve the speed for ST_DWithin

Tags: postgis, postgresql, spatial-index, st-dwithin

I need to get the outer polygon of the LSOAs within 10 miles of each postcode centroid. There are 180k LSOA polygons in table1 and 2.6 million postcode centroid points in table2.

I have created 2 geography columns (`polygon.geog`, `pois.geog`) and one geometry column `polygon.coordinates`. All of them are indexed using GIST.

I tried running for 10 using the code below which took 1 minute.

```
SELECT pois.objectid, ST_Multi(ST_Union(polygon.coordinates)) as coords   
              into table3
              FROM table1 as polygon 
              INNER JOIN table2 as pois 
              ON ST_DWithin(polygon.geog,pois.geog, 10* 1609.34,false)
              group by pois.objectid
            limit 10;
```

Query plan,
[image]

```
[
  {
    "Plan": {
      "Startup Cost": 0.84,
      "Plans": [
        {
          "Partial Mode": "Simple",
          "Startup Cost": 0.84,
          "Plans": [
            {
              "Startup Cost": 0.84,
              "Plans": [
                {
                  "Startup Cost": 0.43,
                  "Scan Direction": "Forward",
                  "Plan Width": 39,
                  "Node Type": "Index Scan",
                  "Plan Rows": 3011500,
                  "Relation Name": "table2",
                  "Alias": "pois",
                  "Parallel Aware": false,
                  "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
                  "Total Cost": 11352214.75,
                  "Index Name": "postcode_pkey"
                },
                {
                  "Filter": "(((pois.geog)::geography && _st_expand(geog, '16093.4'::double precision)) AND _st_dwithin(geog, (pois.geog)::geography, '16093.4'::double precision, false))",
                  "Startup Cost": 0.41,
                  "Scan Direction": "NoMovement",
                  "Plan Width": 11560,
                  "Node Type": "Index Scan",
                  "Index Cond": "(geog && _st_expand((pois.geog)::geography, '16093.4'::double precision))",
                  "Plan Rows": 1,
                  "Relation Name": "table1",
                  "Alias": "polygon",
                  "Parallel Aware": false,
                  "Parent Relationship": "Inner",
                  "Total Cost": 78.31,
                  "Index Name": "gidgeo"
                }
              ],
              "Node Type": "Nested Loop",
              "Plan Rows": 181100,
              "Join Type": "Inner",
              "Parallel Aware": false,
              "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
              "Plan Width": 5783,
              "Total Cost": 247219664.75
            }
          ],
          "Node Type": "Aggregate",
          "Strategy": "Sorted",
          "Plan Rows": 181100,
          "Parallel Aware": false,
          "Group Key": [
            "pois.objectid"
          ],
          "Parent Relationship": "Outer",
          "Plan Width": 39,
          "Total Cost": 247223286.75
        }
      ],
      "Node Type": "Limit",
      "Plan Rows": 1,
      "Parallel Aware": false,
      "Plan Width": 39,
      "Total Cost": 1365.96
    }
  }
]
```

Is it possible to improve the speed of this code?

Comment: what does explain show?

Comment: Do you have indexes for polygon.geog and pois.geog ?

Comment: @RoVo Yes all the three spatial columns are indexed `polygon.geog, pois.geog, polygon.coordinates`

Comment: Running 2.6M unions will take a while, no way around it. You're really trying to create an output table with 2.6M polygons? If your data are not truly global, you could move to a projected system and work in geometry for the dwithin, but you'd still be doing 2.6M unions, so that would be a small improvement, not a huge change.

Comment: Add "`polygon.geog && pois.geog and`" before `ST_DWithin` to force index use. Please remember to always include the query plan in the body of all SQL tuning questions.

Comment: Actually, don't do this ▲. That's not an appropriate index operator for this case, and the correct operator is included automatically.

Comment: @Vince that really improves the speed of the query but generates different output. May be it is not doing what is expected?

Comment: Doh, yeah. It's `ST_Within` that doesn't use the index, not `st_Dwithin`. We really do need the `EXPLAIN` plan to help you. EDIT the question.

Comment: @Vince Thanks for checking into this. I have uploaded the query plan

Comment: You problem is of O(n2) complexity, there is no general way to make that go away... Do you have any (non-spatial) fields that you could use to pre-group the input?

Comment: may I ask what the purpose is? could you maybe just assign a polygon id to each point (group) and work with selecting (and merging) only those polygons you need on the fly?

Comment: @MartinHvidberg I have the field for the county but not sure how to implement your suggestion. And looks like `ST_DWithin` takes about 2 seconds while the `ST_Multi(ST_Union())` takes about 7 seconds per point.

Comment: @ThingumaBob purpose of this is to get the outer polygon of the LSOAs within 10 miles of each postcode centroid.

Comment: how about sth. like `ST_Boundary(ST_Multi(ST_Collect(...)))`? (not 100% sure if *boundary* would get 100% equal results, but `ST_Collect` is definetly faster. suggesting a try)

Comment: @ThingumaBob this gives `MultiLineString` output. which is just the borders of all the polygon. I need one polygon which is a result of the outer polygons.

Comment: sorry I meant `ST_ConvexHull`...but that's still merely a workaround (if even) for the (very costly) point set union. if you're not willing to spend the time, maybe using id references and on-the-fly unions of areas in question would be the way to go

Comment: I was thinking something like:   
      JOIN ...  ON ST_DWithin(polygon.geog,pois.geog, 10* 1609.34,false) AND polygon.country_code = pois.country_code               But you would of cause miss all joins that crosses county borders, so you need to access if that is acceptable.